# C#, Iframes, HTML templates & co

Tags: c#, html, iframe, widget

Let me try to be clear and simple about the problem. I'm currently developing an online player widget. This widget will have a "share" functionality where people will be able to select the format (big vertical, medium horizontal...) and then get the embed code. They'll be able to pre-watch the behaviour of the player they'll export directly through the pop up window opened by clicking on the share button.

I'm facing two problems :

- First : all the behind code and javascript is perfectly operational but the thing is that I don't how to proceed to change the appearance. Writing directly the code from the behind code regarding the pattern obtained from the get or writing several HTML files or a lot of things buzzing in my mind. Would you know the best solution ?
- Segundo : in the pop up, i'm actually calling an iframe displaying exactly the same code aka the same widget from the widget but I'm facing some double Id concurrency problems. I want my changes to be applied in the iframe widget and not the parent one. Do you know thanks to which trick I could avoid that ?

Thanks in advance,

Louis

Comment: Well, I'm coming from PHP so unfortunately a newbie in C#. How is it related ? There must be some technical issues / opportunites I don't master in C# and the way I access DOM elements from the code behind can be related to my problem.